# Uncaught TypeError: this.xx is not a function line 120 (I have defined this 100%)

Tags: javascript

```
xx: function (a) {
    return(this.x+this.r*Math.cos(a));
},
yy: function (a) {
    return(this.y+this.r*Math.sin(a));
},
lerp: function (a,b,x){
    return(a+x*(b-a));
```

These are used to describe how the shapes should be when they are morphed the curves dimmensions of the circle to triangle,

```
var x0=this.xx(sAngle);
var y0=this.yy(sAngle);
var x1=this.xx((eAngle+sAngle)/2);
var y1=this.yy((eAngle+sAngle)/2);
var x2=this.xx(eAngle);
var y2=this.yy(eAngle);
```

This is what is being used and it says its not being defined when it is clearly being defined in the lines

Here is the complete code:

```
var canvas, ctx, fps, radius, width, height;

var ball = [1];

function randomLocation() {

    return 600*Math.random();

}

function randomVelocity(){

    var ran = 2*Math.random();

    if(ran < 1) { return 10*Math.random()}
    else { return -10*Math.random()}
}   

function addBall() {
    ball.push(createBall());
}

function toCircle() {
    for(i=0; i < ball.length; i++) {
        ball[i].toCircle();
    }
}

function toShape() {
    for(i=0; i < ball.length; i++) {
        ball[i].toShape();
    }
}

function createBall() {

    return {x:randomLocation(),
        y:randomLocation(),
        r:radius,
        vx:randomVelocity(),
        vy:randomVelocity(),
        c:getRandomColor(),
        percent: 0,
        percentDirection: 0.50,
        move: function () {
            if(  this.y > height   ){
                this.vy = -this.vy;
            } else if ( this.y < 0 ){
                this.vy = -this.vy;
            }
            if ( this.x > width ){
                this.vx = -this.vx;
            } else if ( this.x < 0 ){
                this.vx = -this.vx;
            }
            this.x += this.vx;
            this.y += this.vy;
        },
        toShape: function () {
            this.percentDirection = -0.50;
        },
        toCircle: function () {
            this.percentDirection = 0.50;
        },
        xx: function (a) {
            return(this.x+this.r*Math.cos(a));
        },
        yy: function (a) {
            return(this.y+this.r*Math.sin(a));
        },
        lerp: function (a,b,x){
            return(a+x*(b-a));
        },          
        draw: function () { 

            var sideCount = 3;

            var sides=[];
            for(var i=0;i<sideCount;i++){
                sides.push(makeSide(i,sideCount));
            }

            drawSides(this.percent);
            this.percent+=this.percentDirection;
            if(this.percent>100){this.percent=100;}
            if(this.percent<0){this.percent=0;}


            var PI2=Math.PI*2;

            // functions

            function drawSides(pct,color){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                if(pct==100){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,PI2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }else{
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(sides[0].x0,sides[0].y0);
                    for(var i=0;i<sideCount;i++){
                        var side=sides[i];
                        var cpx=this.lerp(side.midX,side.cpX,pct/100);
                        var cpy=this.lerp(side.midY,side.cpY,pct/100);        
                        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx,cpy,side.x2,side.y2);
                    }
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }

            function makeSide(n,sideCount){
                var sweep=PI2/sideCount;
                var sAngle=sweep*(n-1);
                var eAngle=sweep*n;

                var x0=this.xx(sAngle);
                var y0=this.yy(sAngle);
                var x1=this.xx((eAngle+sAngle)/2);
                var y1=this.yy((eAngle+sAngle)/2);
                var x2=this.xx(eAngle);
                var y2=this.yy(eAngle);

                var dx=x2-x1;
                var dy=y2-y1;
                var a=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
                var midX=this.lerp(x0,x2,0.50);
                var midY=this.lerp(y0,y2,0.50);
                var cpX=2*x1-x0/2-x2/2;
                var cpY=2*y1-y0/2-y2/2;

                return({
                    x0:x0, y0:y0,
                    x2:x2, y2:y2,
                    midX:midX, midY:midY,
                    cpX:cpX, cpY:cpY,
                    color:randomColor()
                });
            }
        }
    };

}

// this is where we can draw our shapes!

function clearCanvas(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
}

function draw() {
    clearCanvas();

    for( i=0; i < ball.length; i++) {
        ball[i].move();
        ball[i].draw();
    }
}

// this function initializes our variables when the
// page loads

function init(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ball[0] = createBall();

    radius = 20;
    width = 1000;
    height = 600;
}

// This function starts the animation loop
// when the window loads

window.onload = function () {
    init();
    animloop();                                   
}

// This is the looping animation function
// the variable fps sets hows many frames are shown
// per second
function animloop() {

    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    draw();

}

// The function below sends a request to reload the canvas
// 60 times every second

window.requestAnimFrame = (
function(){ return window.requestAnimationFrame|| 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame         || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame            || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame              || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame             || 
    function( callback ){ 
        return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }; 
}
)();

//this function returns a string
// that represents a random hexadecimal color

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: Does `this` point to what you think it does...?

Comment: Yes it does look in complete code @tymeJV

Comment: You sure? You're using `this` pretty liberally, without any `bind`s, which can cause no end of problems due to JS's late `this` binding. I strongly suspect `this` is the issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton Im pretty new to JS what do binds do exactly in simple terms if you can or just flat out explain it, whatever is easier for you

Comment: did you breakpoint or console log `this` in `makeSide`? It must not be correct

Comment: @timperson `bind` creates a new function with `this` bound to whatever you pass in to the `bind` function. You'd be better off looking around for JS `this` tutorials/blogs, it'll probably take a page or two of text to explain it all. Nutshell: the value of `this` depends entirely on how/where/when the function is called, and how the function was created (e.g., "normally", with a `bind`, etc). It can be a bit tricky to completely figure out.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks ill try to figure it out im still open to all other comments though

Comment: Ok the answer fixed it but now it says randomCollor is not defined @DominicTobias

Comment: @DaveNewton now random collor isnt working

Answer (score 0):

You have a `context` problem, where you are calling a function and expecting it to have the right context. The problem can be simplified:

```js
var obj = {
    
    fruit: 'apple',
  
    draw: function() {
        console.log('Fruit1 is:', this.fruit); // apple
        
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            makeSide();
        }
        
        function makeSide() {
            console.log('Fruit2 is:', this.fruit); // undefined
        }
    }
    
};

obj.draw();
```

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or call the function to specify a context, change:

```
sides.push(makeSide(i,sideCount));
```

To:

```
sides.push(makeSide.call(this, i, sideCount));
```

Or somewhere before the call is executed you can bind it so that it is always called with the right context, e.g:

```
makeSide = makeSide.bind(this);
```

Your code as a whole could really use some re-thinking though and this is just applying a band-aid to poor design.

Comment: It might be clearer to call `bind` on `makeSide`; I find using `call` makes the mainline code harder to reason about. (Using `bind` makes the method code a little harder to think about, but it's also local. It also only makes sense if you don't need to bind different things.)

Comment: @timperson it will be another issue where you need to bind or call the function

Comment: fixed it but now this.lerp is not defined can you give me another fix sorry im really new to this and im at camp soooo my counsoler cant even figure it out and hes  busy helping others as well @Dominic Tobias

Comment: i also copied and pasted this from another code and tried to incorporate into my own @Dominic Tobias